# How to get `geom` part from ST_Dump using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy2

I want to translate following SQL-query into the Python code using SQLAlchemy.

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Linemerge(ST_Union(geog::geometry)))).geom
FROM my_table
GROUP BY some_foreign_key
```

I had a partial success with

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from sqlalchemy import func, cast

data = session.query(
    func.ST_Dump(
        func.ST_Linemerge(
            func.ST_Union(
                cast(MyTable.geog, Geometry)
            )
        )
    ).label('dumped_geom')
).group_by(
    MyTable.some_foreign_key
)
```

The issue is that [`ST_Dump`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) returns set instead of single value and this query in Python returns string with a `path` and `geometry` and I need only `geometry` part. [Documentation for `ST_Dump` in geoalchemy2](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spatial_functions.html#geoalchemy2.functions.ST_Dump) doesn't help at all.

Comment: you can turn it around: `select geom from st_dump(...);`

Comment: @JGH any idea how to rewrite query in Python?

Answer (score 0):

geoalchemy2 provides a `ST_Dump` function (wich return an object with a `geom` property)

Ex:

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from geoalchemy2.functions import ST_Dump
from sqlalchemy import cast, func

data = session.query(
    ST_Dump(
        func.ST_Linemerge(
            func.ST_Union(
                cast(MyTable.geog, Geometry)
            )
        )
    ).geom
).group_by(
    MyTable.some_foreign_key
)
```